# Maple 11 Enable Multithreading

Tags: maple

How to enable multithreading in Maple 11 ? I can't find this thing in preferences. kernelopts(multithreaded); - gives me false, how to set it true? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are launching the commandline interface of Maple 11 then you should be able to use the `-M` option.

Eg, on Linux, say,

```
$ maple -M
   |\^/|     Maple 11 (X86 64 LINUX)
._|\|   |/|_. Copyright (c) Maplesoft, a division of Waterloo Maple Inc. 2007
 \  MAPLE  /  All rights reserved. Maple is a trademark of
 <____ ____>  Waterloo Maple Inc.
      |       Type ? for help.

> kernelopts(multithreaded);
                                 true
```

This does not seem to work if the GUI is launched similarly, ie. via `maple -x -M` at the commandline.

I recall that on MS-Windows the launch icon for the GUI brings up a dialogue window that asks whether to start with the serial or parallel kernel.

Which platform are you on, and which interface are you trying to run?

[edited] In the Standard GUI, multithreading in the Maple kernel is enabled by the checkbox "Enable SMP support" in the preferences dialogue window opened by the main menubar Tools -> Options -> General

Comment: I work on windows (really mac, on virtual machine is windows), Maple 11 Classic Worksheet. I do not have Tools -> Options -> General, unfortunately.

Comment: On a Mac (OS X) the preferences should be accessible from Preferences in the Maple 11 menu (as opposed to Tools->Options on MS-Win/Linux/Unix). Once you can check the "Enable SMP support" box you may still need to start a new kernel (ie. Worksheet/Document tab).